# Setting initial Edittext value to blank on focus

Tags: android

I have 4 edit text fields in my app which take in one long and 3 double values respectively. I have used them with onFocusChangedListener(). My issue is whenever a certain edit text gains focus a default (0.0 in case of double) is displayed into the edit field before the user enters the values. I want them to to be blank before the user enters his values. I have tried using editText.setText("") and editText.setHint(""). But these work when the activity starts, but once the edit field gains focus the default values are shown.
Please help me with the glitches.
Thank you.

Heres the code

```
public void onFocusChange(View EditTextFocus , boolean hasFocus)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            km= Long.parseLong(ETKm.getText().toString());
            fuelQty= Double.parseDouble(ETFuelQty.getText().toString());
            fuelPrice= Double.parseDouble(ETFuelPrice.getText().toString());
            totalCost= Double.parseDouble(ETTotalCost.getText().toString());

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(ETTotalCost.hasFocus())
            {

                if((fuelQty!=0)&&(fuelPrice!=0))
                totalCost=fuelQty*fuelPrice;
                ETTotalCost.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalCost));
            }   

        else if(ETFuelQty.hasFocus())
            {
                ETFuelQty.setText("");
                if((fuelPrice!=0)&&(totalCost!=0))
                    fuelQty= (int) (totalCost/fuelPrice);
                    ETFuelQty.setText(String.valueOf(fuelQty));
            }   

        else if(ETFuelPrice.hasFocus())
            {
                ETFuelPrice.setText("");
                if((fuelQty!=0)&&(totalCost!=0))
                    fuelPrice=totalCost/fuelQty;
                    ETFuelPrice.setText(String.valueOf(fuelPrice));
            }   

        }
```

Comment: **but that doesn't help.** - Means????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It might prove useful for others searching this as well.

My issue was that I was initializing and parsing my variables before they came in focus. This made me get the initial values ie. null (0) values in the edit fields when in focus.
I initialized and parsed my variables after the edit fields gained focus

So, I changed my code to:

```
*case R.id.ETTotalCost:
                                if(ETTotalCost.hasFocus())
                                {
                                    if(ETFuelQty.length()>0 && ETFuelPrice.length()>0)
                                    {
                                        fuelQty=Double.parseDouble(ETFuelQty.getText().toString());
                                        fuelPrice= Double.parseDouble(ETFuelPrice.getText().toString());
                                        if((fuelQty!=0)&&(fuelPrice!=0))
                                        totalCost=fuelQty*fuelPrice;
                                        ETTotalCost.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalCost));
                                    }
                                }*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `setHint()` to something.

A *hint* is a placeholder until the person enters some input, so you can put something like "Fuel price".

Comment: I had already tried that. Hints get displayed in the edit texts when the activity starts. in my case when activity starts I do have the edit fields blank. The issue is when the edit fields gain focus 0.0 and 0 are displayed respectively whereas I want them to be blank on focus

Comment: can you please suggest me some other ways. Iam just stuck here

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar I think this is something that is phone specific and my advice would be to just skip trying to *hack* a solution together because any solution you may have could cause more problems on other phones and this seems like a minor nuisance.

Comment: @Emil.. I guess you are right. I have tried out almost everything but nothing seems to work.